# interation problem using Pow() and For loop in Sympy Python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use indexed expression that has pow() function such that:

```py
f = Pow(x[k] - x[l], (-1.0/2.0))
```

where x is an indexed variable.

By using  for loops:

```py
for j in range (n):
    f1 = f.subs(k, j)
    for m in range (n):
        E += f1.subs(l, m)
```

My output is simply `(x[k] - x[l])**(-0.5)`. I already check possible syntax mistakes with index variables definition. If I work without powers (only using the argument of `pow` in the loop) the output is of the form that I expected.

Comment: Don't write `Pow(..., (-1.0/2.0)) `. Sympy doesn't like floats. Write it as `Pow(..., S(1)/2)`. See [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers).

Comment: I find out that i was missing to remove the parameters that involves undefined expressions  also i used your suggestion and the code works pretty well so far. Thanks a lot!